# Merging many documents into one in Word 2007: How to make each one start on a new page?

Tags: microsoft-word, merge

I have 31 documents I need to merge into one, using Word 2007 on Windows 7. I read that you can go to `Insert` -> `Object` -> `Text from file` and select the documents you need. I did that and it worked fine. The thing is, each document is right against the last one. Is there any way to make it so each document starts on a new page, other than manually inserting page breaks?

Here are some example pictures in case it's not clear. Suppose "document1" and "document2" are two documents I want to merge.

How Word does it:
[image: how word does it]

How I want it to be:
[image: how it should be]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a newpage feature in MS-Word. Here you can find more on office 2003
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-a-manual-page-break-HP005189549.aspx
For the other Office versions read the links below:

[Office 2007](http://www.msoffice-tutorial-training.com/word-2007-page-break.html)
[Office 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-a-page-break-HA010031062.aspx)

If you want to read up on MS Office Document structure read take a look at this link:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/CH006082987.aspx

EDIT:

Use this Macro, it will throw an error, if you have no open document:

```
Sub OpenMultipleFiles()
Dim fDialog As FileDialog

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fDialog
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
If .Show <> -1 Then
MsgBox "Cancelled By User", , "Cancelled"
Exit Sub
End If
End With
For i = 1 To fDialog.SelectedItems.Count
Selection.InsertFile fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(i)
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

Next i
End Sub
```

While in Word press ALT+F11 this brings up the VBA Editor. Afterwards expand Normal to see the Modul folder. If it does not exist click on Normal -> Insert -> Modul
Paste the Macro and save.

Afterwards you can add a button with the macro to your toolbars.

Comment: I already know that; I was asking for a way to tell Word to insert this automatically each time a new document is appended.

Comment: use the macro from the edit above

Comment: @Javier Badia is the macro above working in Word 2007?

Comment: @Javier Badia thanks for the info. Then i will save it for myself. I'm not using windows at the moment but one does never know, if it comes in handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't automate it at import, but I do know there is a quick way of inserting page breaks by pressing `Ctrl` + `Enter` before the first word of each new document.

Comment: If nothing else appears, this will be helpful. Thanks. BTW, since all the documents have the same structure, wouldn't it be possible to use something like VBA to automatically insert them at the right places?