# In Office 365 Word, how do I merge several word files into one in order?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, merge

I want to merge about 500 word documents into one. Each document is 2 pages long, and their names is a three digit number, and they are in order: document 001 goes before 006, even 003 to 005 do not exist for example.

I have thought in exporting each document to pdf, then merging them into one. However, because of work restrictions, **I cannot use the Internet by any means.**

Also, [as this post asked](https://superuser.com/questions/246856/merging-many-documents-into-one-in-word-2007-how-to-make-each-one-start-on-a-ne) I need each document to begin in a new page, not begining just after the last ended.

That is all, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the post linked above, using this simple code:

```
Sub OpenMultipleFiles()
Dim fDialog As FileDialog

Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fDialog
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
If .Show <> -1 Then
MsgBox "Cancelled By User", , "Cancelled"
Exit Sub
End If
End With
For i = 1 To fDialog.SelectedItems.Count
Selection.InsertFile fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(i)
Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

Next i
End Sub
```

You just have to open a blank word document, set the margins that the documents you want to merge use, and then open VAB and execute the code.